# Issues in Integrating Authorize.net API's

Tags: android

I'm integrating the Authorized.net Gateway to my Android application.  To test the feature:

1) I downloaded the SDK anet_android_sdk-1.3.0.

2) Compiled the anet_android_sdk-1.3.0, it complained about the missing jar file anet-java-sdk-android-2.0.4. I modified the project to include anet-java-sdk-android-2.0.5 jar file. With that the compilation went successfully.

3) anet_android_sdk. Executable jar file was created successfully in the Bin Directlry.

4) I proceeded for the [example program](https://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/android)

On compiling the Sample code there was alot of WEIRD error thrown by the compiler which are really adsurb.

> Syntax error on token "(", ; expected ExampleActiviy.java /Authorize Android Example/src/net/authorize    line 116    Java Problem
>
> Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)  ExampleActiviy.java /Authorize Android Example/src/net/authorize    line 116    Java Problem
>
> Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens   ExampleActiviy.java /Authorize Android Example/src/net/authorize    line 120    Java Problem
>
> Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements  ExampleActiviy.java /Authorize Android Example/src/net/authorize    line 120    Java Problem
>
> Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement    ExampleActiviy.java /Authorize Android Example/src/net/authorize    line 48 Java Problem
>
> Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block    ExampleActiviy.java /Authorize Android Example/src/net/authorize    line 120    Java Problem
>
> Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody    ExampleActiviy.java /Authorize Android Example/src/net/authorize    line 120    Java Problem
>
> Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody   ExampleActiviy.java /Authorize Android Example/src/net/authorize    line 120    Java Problem
>
> Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete IfStatement ExampleActiviy.java /Authorize Android Example/src/net/authorize    line 120    Java Problem

Assuming that there is some error, I downloaded the SampleProgram code from your url and after quite hardship was able to compile.

But unfortunately when I ran the app "Sdk Test Harness"  it just threw the exception and closed.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: please help me the authroize.net api.problem is integrate the api

Comment: Hi Phoenix and Nitesh Khosla if you have found out the solution of the problem.Please tell me what you tried.I really need the solution.

Comment: Dear now i day i am also facing the same problem in my application when i integrate Authorized.net, Dear if you solved this problem then please give reference for solving it my emial id ravishankar.ahirwar@gmail.com please drop a mail if you have thanks in advence

Answer (score 0):

It is beacuse of copy and paste of code from site.. The new line characters from html is not properly handled in Eclipse. So, copy it line by line or write it.